# Blank page removal tool for PDF?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf, automation

A command line tool is preferred, but not required.

Preview and PDF Pen and dozens of other apps can delete arbitrary pages from a PDF file and save the result. The key problem I can’t solve is how to systematically detect a blank page and have it deleted. Blank is defined as no visible line or text or content.

Do you know of any tool that can detect and remove blank pages from a multi-page PDF file and be controlled by automation (script / Automator / something other than click, look, click)?

Comment: By "blank", do you mean "completely empty", or "no visible marks", or "not many visible marks"? For instance, imagine a page with exactly one text character on it—a space character. It would have no visible marks, but would not be completely empty. Or feed a blank piece of paper into a scanner which generates PDF files. The PDF file would have an image of a blank piece of paper, likely with some light grey spots or flecks due to tricks of light and dust. Would that page be "blank"? The distinction matters a lot for how a page removal tool would detect whether a page is "blank".

Comment: By "blank" I mean "not many visible marks."  See this thread where I posted a link to a scan of a "blank" page.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245785/detecting-empty-pages-in-scanned-documents/13185209#13185209

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few tools I found on the web. I haven't used them, so I can't comment on how well they might work for you.

[**A-PDF Scan Optimizer**](http://www.a-pdf.com/faq/how-to-detect-and-delete-blank-scanned-pdf-pages-with-threshold-value-manually-defining.htm) has an option for detecting and removing pages with not many visible marks.

[the CoolUtils **TIFF PDF Cleaner**](http://www.coolutils.com/tiffpdfcleaner) "detects blank pages in TIFF and PDF files and deletes them".

[Edocfile's **Blank Page Remover**](http://edocfile.com/Blank_Page_Remover.htm) has the effect of deleting blank pages from a PDF file, though it's intended for use with a scanner and a printer as a way of converting a document with mixed single- and double-sided sheets into a document with all single- or double-sided sheets.

[Axpertsoft's **PDF Page Remover**](http://www.axpertsoft.com/pdf-blank-page-removal/) can remove blank pages from multiple PDF files at a single command.

All these requires Windows of some flavour, so I hope you have a virtual machine on your Mac.